# How to connect local symfony 4 project with Online Database

Tags: mysql, pdo, symfony4

my configuration look like this

> ```
> doctrine:
>   dbal:
>     driver: 'pdo_mysql'
>     server_version: '5.7'
>     charset: utf8mb4
>     host: '%env(DATABASE_HOST)%'
>     port: '%env(DATABASE_PORT)%'
>     user: '%env(DATABASE_USER)%'
>     password: '%env(DATABASE_PWD)%'
>     dbname: '%env(DATABASE_NAME)%'
>     url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
> ```

in 
.env

> ```
> DATABASE_HOST=98.***.***.121
> DATABASE_PORT=3306
> DATABASE_USER=user
> DATABASE_PWD=pass
> DATABASE_NAME=database
> ```

but i have this error

An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Une tentative de connexion a chou car le parti connect na pas rpondu convenablement au-del dune certaine dure ou une connexion tablie a chou car l
  hte de connexion na pas rpondu.

Answer (score 0):

That's a timeout.

You need to check the IP address and port are correct, that the port is open in your firewall and that the MySQL daemon is correctly running on your server.